# $\lVert A^TA\rVert_2$=$\lVert A\rVert_2^2$ and $\kappa_2(A^TA)=\kappa_2(A)^2$

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

I have a question from James Demmel's book. Chapter 2 Question 2.10

Let A be n $\times$ m matrix with n$\geq$m,  show that $\lVert A^TA\rVert_2$=$\lVert A\rVert_2^2$ and $\kappa_2(A^TA)=\kappa_2(A)^2$

and Let M be n $\times$ n and positive definite and L be its Cholesky factor so that $M = LL^T$. Show that $\lVert M \rVert_2$ = $\lVert L\rVert_2^2$ and $\kappa_2(M)=\kappa_2(L)^2$.

What I try is not correct and I cannot reach the proof.

Comment: Please remind us how $\| A \|_2$ and $\kappa_2(A)$ are defined. Also, since many of us don't have Demmel's book, state what the context is. Has the singular value decomposition already been introduced at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\|Ax\|^2 = \langle Ax, Ax \rangle = \langle x, A^TAx \rangle \le \|x\| \|A^T A x\| \le \|A^TA\|\|x\|^2$. Taking the $\sup $ over $\|x\| \le 1$
shows that $\|A\|^2 \le \|A^TA\|$.

$\langle u, A^TA v\rangle = \langle A u, A v\rangle \le \|A\|^2 \|u\| \|v\|$. Taking the $\sup$ over $\|u\| \le 1, \|v\|\le 1$ gives $\|A^TA\| \le \|A\|^2$.

$\kappa_2(A^TA) = \|A^T A\| \|(A^T A)^{-1} \| = \|A^T A\| \| A^{-1} A^{-T} \| = \|A\|^2 \|A^{-1}\|^2 = \kappa_2^2(A)$.

The other statement follows immediately from the above.